# Java MongoDB Projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I am referring mongodb official page for projection where I came across following example where elements of array in subdocument is filtered:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

I am trying to implement this in Java but I am not doing it correctly and elements in subdocument array are not filtered.

**Input Collection:**

```
{
   _id: 0,
   items: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2, price: 10 },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 240 }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 1,
   items: [
     { item_id: 23, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 38, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
   ]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    items: [
       { item_id: 4, quantity: 1, price: 23 }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output Collection:**

```
{
   "_id" : 0,
   "items" : [
      { "item_id" : 2, "quantity" : 1, "price" : 240 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "items" : [
      { "item_id" : 23, "quantity" : 3, "price" : 110 },
      { "item_id" : 38, "quantity" : 1, "price" : 300 }
   ]
}
{ "_id" : 2, "items" : [ ] }
```

In Java(mongo Driver 3.9.1), this is what I am doing:

```
Bson priceFilter = Filters.gte("items.price", 100);
mongoCollection.aggregate(
  Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(priceFilter))
);
```

How do I project with aggregate function for the subdocument arrays where I need to filter out elements from subdocument array based on some condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **MongoDB Java Driver 3.9.1**, *collection.aggregate()* takes a *java.util.List* as parameter. So you need to replace your Java code with the below.

```
mongoCollection.aggregate(
  Arrays.asList(
    Aggregates.project(Projections.computed("items",
      new Document().append("$filter",
        new Document().append("input", "$items").append("as", "item").append("cond", 
        new Document().append("$gte", Arrays.asList("$$item.price",100))))))
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks RLD. This code runs successfully.
If I have more fields to the Document, Aggregates.project will remove them. 
Is there a way to leave all other fields untouched as a document may have several other fields too. Using Projections.include(String... fieldNames) would require every filed to be explicitly put here.

Comment: As per MongoDB documentation, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/, to include any other fields(than '_id' field) from the input documents in the output documents, we must explicitly specify the inclusion in $project. So we have to do the same while coding i.e., we have to use Projections.include(String... fieldNames). Please accept my answer if it has resolved your original problem.

Comment: Thanks RLD. Accepted your answer. 

By the way, MongoDB Compass has a feature of exporting aggregates to languages like Java, Python.:
https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-pipeline-to-language/
If we don't want to add all fields explicitly to Projection, We could use $addFields with the filter and it should have similar effect with all existing fields.

Comment: Thanks Hamid. I have to check the $addFields option suggested by you.